# Simulate and estimate probit model

Tags: matlab, regression, probability

I'm trying to simulate and estimate a [probit model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model), but I am not able to produce the expected results. Here is the code i have written so far:

```
N = 10000;
b = [10;-1];

x1 = ones(N,1);
x2 = normrnd(5,1,N,1);
x  = [x1,x2];

u  = randn(N,1);

y  = x*b + u;

y1 = (y>5); 

negLogLik = @(theta) -sum(y1.*log(normcdf(x*theta))+...
                     (1-y1).*log(1-normcdf(x*theta)));
b_hat     = fminunc(negLogLik,[5;-0.8]);
```

Comment: What results are you getting? (What language is this?) :) Forgive the naive question!

Comment: Hi, Barett. Thanks for you answer. It is written in Matlab. I'm getting values very close to the initial values i put in, [5,-.8]. It should be consistent and OLS should also be able to deliver the true values, but that is certainly not the case either.